# How to detect which button user clicked on SKStoreReviewController?

Tags: ios, skstorereviewcontroller

It would be easier to keep track of data and optimize reviews based on how they performed on `SKStoreReviewController` prompts.

But how do we detect which button user clicked? Not now? 1* 4* 5*? Submitted review?

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  If you read the docs for [SKStoreReviewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller) and [requestReview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview), you'll see that it doesn't expose anything about the results, the UI, or whether a prompt was even shown.

Comment: Thats why I'm wondering if there is a private method of accessing those. There probably is and its not going to show up in docs.